# Javascript Object.keys(arr).reduce() return lowest key

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have 3 different test cases, each of which is passed to the function `getEarliest` below:

```
{}

{ '2022-04-29': 1 }

{ '2022-04-29': 3, '2022-04-30': 2, '2022-04-28': 3, '2022-05-02': 2 }
```

From each test case, I want to return the key:value with the smallest date and the biggest value. My problem is at the third test case, I'm getting `'2022-04-29': 3` instead of `'2022-04-28': 3`

```
getEarliest = dates => {

    return Object.keys(dates).reduce((prev, curr) => {

        if (dates[curr] > prev.date) {
        
            return {
                val: dates[curr],
                date: curr
            };
        } else {
            return prev;
        }
    }, {
        val: 0,
        date: null
    }); }
```

expected result test case 1 : `{ val: 0, date: null }`

expected result test case 2 : `{ val: 1, date: '2022-04-29' }`

expected result test case 3 : `{ val: 3, date: '2022-04-28' }`

Comment: You're only matching strings. You're not matching dates.

Comment: you are comparing val with date -> `dates[curr] > prev.date`

Comment: Notice in your `if` you use this condition `dates[curr] > prev.date` in which `dates[curr]` is the value (not the date) so you are comparing the value of the current element against `prev.date` which is the date of the previous one. Instead, to compare the dates you need to use `curr < prev.date` and to compare the value `dates[curr] > prev.val` (you'll need both comparisons in your code)

Comment: Even with `curr < prev.date`, it will only return the initial object with null, because `prev.date` is initially `null` and the comparison will always be false and always return the initial object.

Comment: *"...the smallest date and the biggest value. "* Do you mean smallest date = earliest date? When you say, *"biggest value"*, what if the pair with the earliest date isn't the pair with the highest value -- do want them merged? Also, the input of objects are as is or is there an array wrapped around them?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes, I meant earliest date with the highest value. In case there are multiple equal values, take the earliest date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need just `sort` object by two parametrs:

```js
const test1 = {};
const test2 = { '2022-04-29': 1 };
const test3 = { '2022-04-29': 3, '2022-04-30': 2, '2022-04-28': 3, '2022-05-02': 2 };
const test4 = { '2022-04-29': 4, '2022-04-28': 4, '2022-04-30': 4, '2022-05-02': 2 };

  
const getEarliest = (dates) => {
  const [date, val] = Object.entries(dates)
    .sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2 - v1 || Date.parse(k1) - Date.parse(k2) ) 
    .at(0) ?? [null, 0];

  return { val, date };
};

console.log(getEarliest(test1));
console.log(getEarliest(test2));
console.log(getEarliest(test3));
console.log(getEarliest(test4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And the same result with `reduce`:

```js
const test1 = {};
const test2 = { '2022-04-29': 1 };
const test3 = { '2022-04-29': 3, '2022-04-30': 2, '2022-04-28': 3, '2022-05-02': 2 };
const test4 = { '2022-04-29': 4, '2022-04-28': 4, '2022-04-30': 4, '2022-05-02': 2 };

  
const getEarliest = (dates) => {
  const [date, val] = Object.entries(dates)
    .reduce((prev, curr) => (curr[1] - prev[1] || Date.parse(prev[0]) - Date.parse(curr[0])) > 0  
      ? curr 
      : prev
    , [null, 0]);
  
  return { val, date };
};

console.log(getEarliest(test1));
console.log(getEarliest(test2));
console.log(getEarliest(test3));
console.log(getEarliest(test4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `prev.date` value is initially null. so `reduce()` will always return the initial object.

Try this code it's help you

```
 getEarliest = (dates) => {
      if (Object.keys(dates).length > 0) {
        let date = Object.keys(dates).reduce((prev, curr) => {
          if (prev > curr) {
            return curr;
          } else {
            return prev;
          }
        });

        return {
          val: dates[date],
          date: date
        }
      } else {
        return {
          val: 0, date: null
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 2 sort conditions so they have to be put in a certain order. From your examples I assume that order is: "biggest value" -> "smallest date". Then your `if` will become like below:

```js
getEarliest = (dates) => {
  return Object.keys(dates).reduce(
    (prev, curr) => {
      if (dates[curr] > prev.val || (dates[curr] === prev.val && curr < prev.date)) {
        return {
          val: dates[curr],
          date: curr,
        }
      } else {
        return prev
      }
    },
    {
      val: 0,
      date: null,
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- In the first statement the `.date` property was never defined so it  should be `undefined`. `dates` is an array not an object so `dates[curr]` looks like `dates['2022-04-28']` which isn't helpful. In notation form ex. `array[5]` an interger goes in the bracket as the index which is the 3rd parameter of `.reduce()`

  ```
  if (dates[curr] > prev.date) {...
  ```
- The reason you get `"2022-04-29"` is because the array is never changed, you need to acrually sort the dates with `.sort()` a simplier method or `.reduce()` too complex for a novice.

***Details are commented in the example below***

```js
let A = {};

let B = {
  '2022-04-29': 1
};

let C = {
  '2022-04-29': 3,
  '2022-04-30': 2,
  '2022-04-28': 3,
  '2022-05-02': 2
};

// Optional utility function
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

/*
Can convert from timestamp to YYYY-MM-DD and vice versa
*/
const dX = (number, string) => {
  let D;
  if (number) {
    let date = new Date(number);
    D = ` ${date.getFullYear()}-${("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)}-${("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)}`;
  } else if (string) {
    D = Date.parse(string);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
  return D;
};

// Pass tS = {...}
const getEarliest = tS => {
  // if tS is empty...
  if (Object.keys(tS).length === 0) { // Return premade object
    return {
      val: 0,
      date: null
    };
  }
  /*
  Object.entries(tS) converts {k: v, k: v,...} into [[k,v], [k,v]...]
  */
  /*
  .map(([k, v]) exposes key/value
  pairs by destructuring [k, v]
  */
  /*
  .sort(a, b) is referencing each
  date key and converting it into
  a number (ms since epoch)
  */
  let table = Object.entries(tS).map(([k, v]) => [k, v]).sort((a, b) => dX(null, a[0]) - dX(null, b[0]));
  let obj = {};
  obj.val = table[0][1];
  obj.date = table[0][0];
  return obj;
};

log(getEarliest(A));
log(getEarliest(B));
log(getEarliest(C));
```